# How to Copy/Paste large number of lines of code in a terminal

Tags: terminal, copy-paste

I am working on `mySQL` source. I need to `copy` a file with 12,000 lines of code at a time and `paste` it into another terminal/text document. How can I perform this task?

Comment: okay i have rejected it @Mogsdad

Answer (score 2):

Use the `cat` command so that it allows you to `select all text` and paste it in another terminal where u require

Comment: wat was ur output needed did u get?

Comment: Actually `cat` command allows to select only particular amount of the text,not the entire text.